# What is the use of word "Greetings!..." while sending an email?

Tags: word-usage, greetings

I have seen many people who start writing their email like as follows..

> > Dear XXXX
>
> Greetings!!!.
>
> Thanks etc...

I just want to know the meaning of the word greeting in this context.

Thanks

Comment: It means you've been drafted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is essentially the same as "Hello" or "Hi" or "Good day."  Perhaps a little more formal, or at least potentially so, in that it does not require the writer to decide whether the recipient of the e-mail is close enough for "hi" versus the more formal (at least in the US) "hello" or "good day."